# PSUBSCRIBE and GEOADD

Tags: redis

I’m having a pretty basic Redis pubsub issue, I want to `PSUBSCRIBE` to items added via the `GEOADD` command. Here is what I’ve done:

First have the `MONITOR` command running.

Then in a new console I’ve also run:

```
PSUBSCRIBE __geo:*
```

Then in another `redis-cli` session I’ve issued:

```
GEOADD users 40.0 -73.0 foo
```

Nothing comes up for the subscriber but I can confirm the item was added via the MONITOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 Things:

1) Make sure that you have the correct `CONFIG SET` for keyspace events. `CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events AKE` will get everything which is OK for debugging, but you'll most likely just need `CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events zE` for your use case.

2) All Redis GEO* commands are actually [just a version of a sorted set](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd). They don't have their own notification. `GEOADD` will actually show up like `ZADD` in the keyevents message. Also, the keyspace events are formatted a little differently. You'll want to do a `SUBSCRIBE __keyevent@0__:zadd` to listen for `GEOADD` commands.

3) Since GEO* and Z* commands are actually *sets*, commands that don't trigger a write won't trigger a keyevent. So, multiple `GEOADD` will not yield multiple events.

Take this:

PubSub Client:

```
SUBSCRIBE __keyevent@0__:zadd
1) "subscribe"
2) "__keyevent@0__:zadd"
3) (integer) 1
```

Normal Client: `GEOADD users 40.0 73.0 foo`

PubSub Client:

```
1) "message"
2) "__keyevent@0__:zadd"
3) "users"
```

Normal Client: `GEOADD users 40.0 73.0 foo`

PubSub Client:

```
 (nothing)
```

Comment: ... and the simplest way to get the desired result is forgo the keyspace notifications and just bundle every `GEOADD` with a respective `PUBLISH`, possibly w/ a Lua script ;)

Comment: you think just in a `multi` transaction this is fine?